# Downloading source from arxiv only gives one figure. How to obtain the entire TeX source?

Tags: arxiv, source

I would like to download the TeX source code of this paper (https://arxiv.org/format/1701.07035v2) from arXiv. But clicking "Download source" only gives me one figure in the paper. Does anyone know how to obtain the entire TeX source from the arXiv?

Thanks!

Comment: did you make sure to click on the (text) download source link not the button download pdf?

Comment: It now works! I think my browser was uncompressing automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading and unzipping the archive from the [link you posted](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1701.07035v2) shows a directory of files and figures.

[image]

How are you unzipping the directory?  The issue could be there.

Comment: Dear Prunus, Thanks very much! I clicked "Download source" on Firefox, and the downloaded file is automatically a figure. I also tried Chrome, I got the same figure. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I used Firefox, though that shouldn't be a factor.  You should be getting a download of a zip file called `1701.07035v2`, and then unzipping it.

Comment: It now works! I think my browser was uncompressing automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically caused by the browser behavior called "open safe files". If this is enabled, `.zip` and `.gz` will be automatically uncompressed, which leaves them in a confusing state. arXiv's source packages deliver `.tar.gz` for files containing more than a single file (but the file extension is missing for source package downloads for historical reasons), so your browser is uncompressing them into `.tar` files without telling you. Whatever reader you're using to view the source package is probably able to recognize the first file in the compressed package and is only displaying that file to you.